# unable trigger uiview.animate when placed inside a function in swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I am unable to trigger the animation, I put the function below outside the `viewdidload` function and created a custom function that will be trigger when the button is tapped. But instead of it creating the animation it gave me an error below. this is the error

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

this is the function that going to be triggered

```
@objc func triggeranimation(){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            let intro:introViewController = introViewController()
            intro.Title.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        }, completion: nil)
    }
```

and I added button programmatically inside viewdidload that will trigger the function above. I try to put the custom func above before and after `viewdidload` function with the same error result. please help why is it telling me that it found nil when I clearly in the same view controller.

```
let nextBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
        nextBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        nextBtn.setTitle("Next", for: UIControlState.normal)
        nextBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        nextBtn.addTarget(self, action: Selector("triggeranimation"), for: .touchUpInside)
        nextBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        self.view.addSubview(nextBtn)
        // width cant change for some unknown reason
        nextBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10)
        nextBtn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20)
        nextBtn.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        nextBtn.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
```

complete code

```
class introViewController: UIViewController{
    var Title:UILabel!
    var nextBtn:UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
 let Title = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width / 2, y: (self.view.frame.size.height + 30), width: 50, height: 10))
        Title.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        Title.text = "WELCOME"
        Title.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24, weight: .bold)
        Title.textAlignment = .center
        Title.textColor = UIColor.black
        self.view.addSubview(Title)
        Title.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -250).isActive = true
        Title.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

let nextBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
        nextBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        nextBtn.setTitle("Next", for: UIControlState.normal)
        nextBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        nextBtn.addTarget(self, action: Selector("triggeranimation"), for: .touchUpInside)
        nextBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        self.view.addSubview(nextBtn)
        // width cant change for some unknown reason
        nextBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10)
        nextBtn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20)
        nextBtn.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        nextBtn.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true


}

@objc func triggeranimation(){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            let intro:introViewController = introViewController()
            intro.Title.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

in addition, i also tried to move UIView.animate inside the viewdidload but it did not animate at all, it just change the color instantly.

UPDATE: i did solve the found nil problem, by  changing Title variable 
`var Title:UILabel!` into `var Title:UILabel! = UILabel()`

but i still have a problem with animation, it did not make any animation just instantly change the color even when i make the DURATION longer into 5.0

Comment: what you have in your `introViewController()` ?

Comment: i have one func above, one uibutton above and one label name title. that will change background color when the button clicked

Comment: the question is how you instantiate the `introViewController`. Because if you use an interface file and don't load it the ui elements will be `nil`.

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question lead to a misunderstanding. What is your variable `introViewController` ? How are you instantiating it ?

Comment: i added the title label by adding  var Title:UILabel! on the top then i add it to view with view.addsubview on theviewdidload like the button above

Comment: i added the complete code, this is what it look like on my screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `intro` is a newly initialized view controller which is completely unrelated to the instance in question.  For example, viewDidLoad will not be called on that new instance. Instead, you just want to use "self", meaning THE loaded view controller.

```
@objc func triggeranimation(){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        //let intro:introViewController = introViewController()
        self.Title.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

There also seems to be a problem in your viewDidLoad code, where you are trying to initialize the Title and nextBtn properties. Instead, you are accidentally creating a local constant of the same name.  This is why your properties are nil.

```
 // You have this now, which creates a local constant
 //let Title = UILabel(.. 

 // You want this instead, which initializes your property
 self.Title = UILabel(..
```

Do the same for nextBtn, of course.

Comment: i did that still and still have the same result

Comment: you are close. but i change it from var Title:UILabel! into `var Title:UILabel! = UILabel()`